# Insert Data using entity framemodel

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I am a student and working on a college project.

I have created a simple scenario which I am facing in my project.

The simple database looks like this.

```
**Location Table**

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location] (
    [Id]        INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [longitude] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [latitude]  VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
**Role Table**

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Role] (
        [Id]   INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [Name] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
    );
**Another table**

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Another] (
        [Id]   INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [Anything] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
    );
**User Table**

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
        [Id]      INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [name]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
        [address] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
        [loc_id]  INT          NOT NULL,
        [role_id] INT          NOT NULL,
         [another_id] INT          NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
        CONSTRAINT [FK_User_lococation] FOREIGN KEY ([loc_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_User_another] FOREIGN KEY ([another_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Another] ([Id]),
            CONSTRAINT [FK_User_role] FOREIGN KEY ([role_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Role] ([Id])

        );
```

I have populated Role table with following values

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3etc.jpg)

Now I want to add user using **EntityFrameWorkCore**

My controller looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Address,RoleId")] User user)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(user);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    ViewData["LocId"] = new SelectList(_context.Location, "Id", "Id", user.LocId);
    ViewData["RoleId"] = new SelectList(_context.Role, "Id", "Id", user.RoleId);
    return View(user);
}
```

The problem is I want to Add User but it doesn't have a foreign key of Location table and Another table.

**How can I create a Location_id and Another_id and put in User**

I want my User object to get the foreign key of location table and another table.

Please help me, I don't know how to do that it will great help for me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have info about FK, don't generate it randomly, make foreign key column nullable in class user. Surely, when you are using EF you have navigation properties in `User` class. You can add also `int` property which stores `id` of associated entity (this is advised, so if you don't have, create such property). Type of this property should (obviously) nullable, so use `int?`. Then update database, so FK column in DB will be also nullable. Then you will be able to insert `user` entity.